# Android: How to save current results / data before going to child activity?

Tags: android

How to save current results / data before going to child activity so that I can restore the data when will press system up button at child activity?

Answer (score 0):

use `onPause` and `onResume` method of the activity

More info in the training [guides](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

Your activities data isnt lost when it goes deeper in the hierarchy unless you finish the activity.

Another solution which is better is use `startActivityForResult`
That is explained in detail [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: I also tried startActivityForResult..

But, I noticed that onActivityResult is not be called when pressing up button at child activity.

Comment: then ? please explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`saveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) for saving the data needed later when reopening the activity.

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/1101730

**EDIT:** It seem like this is usable when the activity is killed, which might not be your case.